# Different Font in a Math Environment

Tags: fonts, math-mode

I would like to use two different fonts in my document, differentiated as follows: In the body/text of my document, I would like to use Times, and in the equations I would like to default to standard computer modern. Additionally, if any text should appear in my math environments, I would like that to be rendered in Times as well. How can this be done?

Comment: Typographically speaking it's not a good idea: they are very different serif fonts and the don't mix at all.

Answer (score 2):

To change just the text-mode font to Times, while leaving the math-mode font family at its default (i.e., Computer Modern), you could issue the command

```
\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{ptm}
```

in your document's preamble.

As the name of the command suggests, this instruction only changes the font for the "roman" text font. As such, the default sans-serif and monospaced font families are also left untouched. If you also wanted to change the *sans-serif* font family from Computer Modern to, say, `Helvetica`, you could add the command

```
\usepackage[scale=0.86]{helvet}
```

where the 0.86 scaling factor is chosen to equalize the "x-heights" of Times Roman and Helvetica. At a given "point size", the x-height of Helvetica is about 20 percent larger than that of Times Roman; if there's a chance that both fonts will occur side by side in a line of text, it's imperative to scale one font or the other so that the x-heights are (roughly) equal.

For the sake of completeness: assuming you have an up-to-date TeX distribution (such as TeXLive2012, or MikTeX2.9 with all packages fully updated) on your computer, you could also issue the command

```
\usepackage{newtxtext}
```

to switch the document's text-mode font to Times Roman. Any differences between the Times Roman text families of the `ptm` and `newtxtext` groups will be very subtle.

Comment: Thanks very much Mico! One further question: In opposition to my original question, what if I wanted text in my math environments to be in computer modern?

Comment: An interesting (and slightly unusual) concern. It wouldn't be hard to achieve: just encase the text in question in `\mathrm` directives, taking care to specify interword spaces explicitly with `\ ` directives. E.g., $\mathrm{The\ quick\ brown\ fox\ jumps.}$ would be rendered in Computer Modern.

Comment: @Mico: You are misusing `\mathrm`. If the text is really "text" then it should be set in "text" mode (e.g. with `\text` or `\mbox` and the font family should be switched like in the text body by using `\fontfamily{whatever}\selectfont`

Comment: @UlrikeFischer -- My follow-up comment was meant only to address a, shall-we say, unusual query from the OP -- about how to typeset some text in a math environment in CM even though the main text font is TR. I actually fully agree with you that if the text font is TR, then text set inside a math expression should also use TR.

Comment: I didn't say anything about the sense to use different font families for texts portions. I complained about your *method* to change the font family. `\mathrm` is a command for *math symbols*. It should be used to set the font of a single symbol, but not to set the font of a longer text – even if it looks okay in some cases. Try e.g. `\mathrm{abcäöüß}` (with and without T1-encoding) to see some of the possible problems.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: Thanks for providing this clarification. While on the subject raised by the OP's follow-up question: What would be *your* preferred method for rendering a snippet of text inside a math environment (with CM math fonts) in CM if the main text font is, say, TR?

Comment: I don't have one, I do find the idea rather curious. Text is text and should use a text font. But if I had to do it I would do as I suggested above: use `\text` or `\mbox` and change the font family in the same way it is changed in text: with `\fontfamily`.